# I need to highlight the clicked navbar with active class

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, navbar

This is my Navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" DashBoard ","Admin ")">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" SectionsList ","Admin ")">Sections</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" DifficultyList ","Admin ")">Difficulty</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" QuestionsList ","Admin ")">Questions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" AssessmentList ","Admin ")">Assessments</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" UsersList ","Admin ")">User's</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Students</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" StudentResult ","Admin ")">Student Results</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my click function:

```
$("#navbarsExampleDefault li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

I need to highlight the selected navbar with active class. I have tried this one but not working

```
public ActionResult SectionsList()
 {
  return view();
}
```

This is one of  my action method

Comment: [your code seems to work as intended](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/17c0pm6b/)

Comment: i think u have added e.preventDefault(); but it is now highlighting but it is not going to particular page because of this preventDefault.

Comment: after removing e.preventdefault() it is not highlighting with active class

Comment: but in href i have this href="@Url.Action("SectionsList","Admin")" but is not working if i remove url.action then it is working but i need to navigating another page through that one only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var change = function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname;        
    $('ul.navbar-nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');        
};
change();
```

Load this function in the js file which is common to every page and remove class active from li.
Works even when the page reloads.

I hope it works for you! Thanks!

Comment: it is highlight selected one but not removing older active class

Comment: i have updated  your line and it is working fine now $('ul.navbar-nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

Comment: but i have dropdown for the last li it is not getting highlighted

Comment: can you help me on this for last li dropdown

Comment: if (url == '/StudentResult/Admin' ) {
            $('div.dropdown-menu a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().parent().addClass('active');
            $('div.dropdown-menu a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('active');
        }   -- as location.pathname fetches url so I came up with this solution

Answer (score 2):

Place the below edited piece of code which is tested

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".navbar-nav .nav-link").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.nav-item').addClass('active');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
$("#navbarsExampleDefault li a").click(function () {
    $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 });
```

Hope it works for you Thanks!